React Native: FaceID on iOS 18 not calling prompt
Facing pretty new problem with unfortunately dead library react-native-biometrics (same result with react-native-touch-id).
On iOS 17.4 FaceID works as expected, i call prompt and app is waiting for FaceId validation.
On iOS 18, i get an error in console. I see prompt UI ofr a milliseconds, it disappears and it's immediately evaluated as No biometrics provided.
Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1000 "UI service connection invalidated."
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=UI service connection invalidated., NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication failed.}

This error can be due to new Simulator bug, on real devices users cannot login via FaceID.
Here i get Keys do not exist or were deleted
rnBiometrics.biometricKeysExist().then((resultObject) => {
    const { keysExist } = resultObject;

    if (keysExist) {
      console.log('Keys exist');
    } else {
      console.log('Keys do not exist or were deleted');
    }
  });

This is my simplePrompt call
const rnBiometrics = new ReactNativeBiometrics();
try {
    const { success, error } = await rnBiometrics.simplePrompt({
      promptMessage: 'Confirm fingerprint',
      cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
    });

    if (success) {
      Logger.log('Successful biometrics provided');
    }
    if (error) {
      Logger.log(`Biometrics prompt error: ${error}`);
    }

    return success;
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.error('Biometrics prompt failed with exception: ', e);
    return false;
  }

Does anyone dealing with the same?

By trial-and-error, I switched to different iPhone simulators, e.g., iPhone 16 Pro -> iPhone 11 Pro Max, and back and forth, and I was able to get the Simulator working again.
